# Node Authorization pallet using different accounts than alice and bob not working

Tags: pallet-node-authorization, trusted-nodes

I have been unnable to finalize blocks including the node authorization pallet to the runtime and with accounts different to the alice and bob one.

When following the tutorial for trusted nodes without alice and bob, I generate the keys and replace it in place of bob and alice in the customized specs.

I have been guessing that in order to use different accounts than alice and bob and also use the node authorization pallet I should just kind of follow both tutorials at the same time. Adding the keys for the accounts to the storage using key insert command from the chain.

is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain which two tutorials you're using.

However, to ensure functionality, you need to:

1. Clear the old database.
2. Update the specifications and regenerate the spec file.
3. Launch the node with the updated spec file.
4. Add the keys.
5. Reboot the node (updating GRANDPA keys necessitates a restart).